# How does Spring-Boot handle requests that are put through a singleton class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, singleton

I'm currently developing a class structure that uses singleton classes for each RequestMapping. I understand that Spring (by default) handles requests in a multi-threading capacity, but I just want to make sure what I'm laying-out now will eventually work in the way I'm intending.

In addition, if, for instance, I make a request and the singleton class creates an in-memory database. On a successive request from the same user/client, will the next request be able to use any of the information previously stored, or is the Spring container for requests destroyed (of sorts) when the response is send back, and re-created on a new request?

Finally, if this is bad practice in any way to create a singleton class for this purpose, I'm open to any suggestions. The original intent of creating the singleton class, was to simply make the ScheduleManager class responsible for creating the object in its entirety, that way if later, if I need to have certain steps taken beforehand to create a full ScheduleManager object (say for instance, establishing a connection to a database), then I can do that without having to create an extra parameter to the constructor and making the implementing class (RequestController) responsible for creating such a database connection.

```java
// Partial of RequestController.java
@RestController
public class RequestController {

    private static final String DATA_DIR = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RequestController.class);

    @PostMapping(value = "/generateSchedules")
    public JsonObject scheduleRequest(@RequestBody JsonObject requestedClasses) {
        JSONObject request = gsonToJson(requestedClasses);
        JSONObject response = ScheduleManager.getInstance().generateSchedules(request);
        return jsonToGson(response);
    }
}



// Partial of singleton class ScheduleManager
public class ScheduleManager implements RequestManager {

    private static ScheduleHandler handler;

    private ScheduleManager() {}

    private static class ScheduleManagerHolder {
        private static final ScheduleManager INSTANCE = new ScheduleManager();
    }

    public static ScheduleManager getInstance() {
        handler = ScheduleHandler.getInstance();
        return ScheduleManagerHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public JSONObject generateSchedules(JSONObject request) {
        handler.handlePost(request);
        List<Schedule> schedules = GoldPan.getInstance().generate();
        JSONArray schedulesAsJson = listToJsonArray(schedules);

        JSONObject output = new JSONObject();
        output.put("schedules", schedulesAsJson);

        return output;
    }
}
```

So, what I'm expecting, is that each unique client sending a request to the RequestController will have their own separate entity/container of sorts of the ScheduleManager singleton class, rather than sharing a single ScheduleManager amongst all requests (kinda like the label "singleton" implies in my mind).

Comment: First of all, your singleton design is wrong, for example the recursive call to `ScheduleManager#getInstance` is unneeded. The main problem here though seems that you have mixed up what is managed by the IoC container. Your singleton class is not a Spring bean and thus is not managed by it. You simply create it and re-use it. Now the best question here is whether this is what you really need. If for example this class will be responsible for transforming some information passed in from the request then yes it's a good approach but then again, why didn't you just make it a Spring bean?

Comment: @Aris_Kortex I think the recursive part you're seeing might just be my crappy class names. The inner call is `ScheduleHandler#getInstance`(but I've refactored a lot of code since then so that doesn't exist anymore). The singleton class is just responsible for taking in a `JSONObject request`, putting it into Java objects, then operating on those Java objects, creating a new `JSONObject response` and passing that back to the Controller. As for the Spring bean stuff, I'm not that versed with Spring and Spring boot, but I'll look into it and see if that's an option for what I need.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex Follow-up question, if my singleton class is not a Spring bean and isn't handled by the Spring IoC container, does this mean that every request will share the same instance of the class? i.e. If a request comes in for schedules, and it makes some modifications to the member fields, and then shortly after another request comes in for schedules, and it also makes modifications to the member fields, will it be overwriting the modifications made by the first request if it hasn't fully processed yet? If so, I definitely need to switch my class to a Spring bean